# MySQL case sensitivity setting

Tags: mysql, case, case-sensitive

Does anyone know the file name or path where I can change the lower_case_tables_names value on the latest version of MySQL Windows 11?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/option-files.html

Comment: If you are moving from *nix to Windoz, good luck.